# Does a SpriteBatch instance need to call dispose() once it is no longer used?

Tags: libgdx

According to [this article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management), a `SpriteBatch` instance needs to call `dispose()` once it is no longer needed. However, as I examine some of libgdx's official examples like Pax Britannica and Super Jumper, I found out that they never call `SpriteBatch.dispose()`. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SpriteBatch` must always be disposed.

Internally, it creates and manages several `Mesh` objects. These objects allocate vertex/index arrays on the GPU. Those are only deallocated if you explicitly call `Mesh#dispose()`, which will be triggered by calling `dispose()` on your SpriteBatch object.

It will also, by default, create its own `ShaderProgram`. And similarly, would be leaked if you didn't call `dispose()`.

If the demo's aren't doing this, perhaps it's time to send a pull request!

Answer (score 1):

I think the given demo games try to keep things simple. They are supposed to show how the basic things in libgdx work in a minimalistic way and thus also abstract a little of some details. That's useful for beginners to not bloat up the examples with a lot of very specific code.

In a real world example I think `SpriteBatch.dispose()` has to be called in the `dispose()` method of the `GameScreen` in SuperJumper for example. And also `GameScreen.dispose()` has to be called when switching back to the `MainMenuScreen`, because this doesn't happen automatically as well.

When creating a Spritebatch like this `new SpriteBatch()`, it creates one internal `Mesh`. When not calling `SpriteBatch.dispose()` this one mesh would also not be disposed and thus SuperJumper has a memory leak there.

Comment: How do you know "it might not even have any resources left that might cause a memory leak" ? I thought according to that article I posted, `SpriteBatch` is itself a resource? "`There are multiple classes in libgdx which represent such resources.`"

Comment: @HảiPhong Well, a `SpriteBatch` itself is just a standard Java object. When it's not referenced anymore, the garbage collector will get rid of it completely. Problems most of the time only arise when you upload resources to the graphics card, textures being the most easy example here. Those resources aren't automatically reset once the GC cleans up the object. Another example is the Box2D `World`. Here we use JNI to invoke C++ code where a gargabe collector doesn't exist. I just quickly looked at the source of what `SpriteBatch.dispose()` does and it seemed that it might not be necessary.

Comment: OK, I understand about `SpriteBatch`. But then what about `Texture` and `TextureAtlas` and `BitmapFont`? They contains textures so that means these classes must always call `dispose()` right?

Comment: Yes, but I'd advise you to use an `AssetManager` for those classes.

Comment: `SpriteBatch` contains several `Mesh` objects, these themselves allocate vertex/index arrays. These are allocated in graphics memory. If you don't dispose `SpriteBatch` properly, then `Mesh#dispose()` will never be called, and you will leak these arrays on the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I've created games where I have multiple screens which all has their own SpriteBatch. I just removed all dispose() methods of the batches and for me, there's no effect of this. So keep in mind to check for this before releasing your product. Even if you can't feel any downside not to dispose batches, there's no reason not to dispose them. Just do it on the Screen implemententations dispose methos, takes about 1 nano second to do :)